# MongoDB Delete documents that don't have given field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello I have a beginner question I suppose... 
I've had a look around but could not find the answer

I have the following collection of `users` that I'd like to clean before I redefine my user model - how can I remove all documents that don't have the field firstname, or lastname in the following collection ?

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57615777a629d16a4c604cce"), "firstName" : "Hector", "lastName" : "yoyo", "email" : "mail@test.tld", "createDate" : ISODate("2016-06-15T13:26:15.900Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57615849a629d16a4c604ccf"), "firstName" : "Arnaud", "lastName" : "yaya", "email" : "mail@dsdsasadsadsad.tld", "createDate" : ISODate("2016-06-15T13:29:45.517Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57615c33a629d16a4c604cd0"), "createDate" : ISODate("2016-06-15T13:46:27.224Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57615ff943d8b1a74c4d4216"), "createDate" : ISODate("2016-06-15T14:02:33.352Z") }
```

I know I can remove these one by one but I imagine there's a better solution :)

```
db.users.remove( { "_id" : ObjectId("57615ff943d8b1a74c4d4216") } );
```

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Use the **[`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists)** operator in combination with the **[`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)** operator within your remove query:

```
db.users.remove({
    "$or": [
        { "firstName": { "$exists": false } },
        { "lastName": { "$exists": false } }
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#exists) operator with two subsequent calls:

```
db.users.remove({firstName: { $exists: false } })
db.users.remove({lastName: { $exists: false } })
```

Comment: This is good, however you can drop the quote marks all together for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
db.users.remove({
    $or: [
       { firstName: { $exists: false } },
       { lastName: { $exists: false } }
    ] 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').deleteMany({
    "field1":{$exists:false},
    "field2":{$exists:false},
    "field3":{$exists:true}
    })
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**